# Outgoing transfers sent from smart contract now showing on rinkbey block explorer

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I've recently deployed a contract on Rinkbey. On the block explorer it shows all INCOMING transactions to the contract, but when I transfer ether from inside the contract (say, to the owner, or another address), that OUTGOING transaction doesn't show on the block explorer.

I can even check the balance of the receiving address and that is updated, but the receiving address doesn't have the incoming transaction on the block explorer either (but it did receive the ether). Why are these transactions not showing?

[contract link here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x5d6b1b1227732a4b69d9bb70dbe131968df48a4c)

Comment: This should be asked on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

Comment: I noticed the same thing and would like to know as well whether this is a bug or intended by design or missing in the design.